# Load all nodes from content type on front page without views

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I want to create a one-page website. What I hope to be able to do is load all the created pages from one content type under each other, prefably in a for each loop.

So in page.tpl.php it would be something like:

```
foreach($pages as $page){
    print $title;
    print render($page['content']);
}
```

This way I could also bind views/blocks to certain pieces of the page. The reason I'm looking for this kind of approach is to keep the website manageable.

The structure would be as follows:

```
home
about
 - slide one (view)
 - slide two (view)
 - slide three (view)
other page
 - slide one (view)
 - slide two (view)
```

So the mentioned slides are items from a different content type, loaded from a view.

If someone can point me in the right direction, or if some pieces of the question need clearing up, please let me know.

---

If people are still interested in this, I will give my solution here:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->propertyCondition('status', 1) /* Status to make sure it is published */
  ->propertyCondition('type', array('page', 'webform')) /* get pages and webforms */
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_volgorde', 'value', 'ASC') /* a custom field to set the order */
  ->range(0, 9999); /* amount of pages to get */
$result = $query->execute();
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));

foreach($nodes as $node): 
    // Do your code magic
endforeach;
```

Within the foreach, fields can be echoed by using the following code examples:

```
echo $node->title;
echo $node->body['und'][0]['value'];
// ['und'] = language undefined
```

If there are any questions, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom content type with a textarea field for each section of the page (home, about, other).

Create a custom template for you content type and output all of the fields in the proper places. You can add your views as blocks.

Make sense?

Comment: It makes sense, but how would I go about outputting the fields in the proper places? Plus, would this also work with multiple pages. Say, if I would add more pages, could I then dynamically be able to add views as blocks to that?

Comment: you can you page--front.tpl.php as your template since it's your front page.

Comment: Could you give a code example how I would be able to load all pages after each other? I need to be able to give the different pages their own blocks/view-blocks and I get your story, up until the part how this all should get outputted.

Comment: After reading your suggestion again for the 10th time, I finally understand what you mean. I think that it's a good idea. The only downside is that you can't dynamically add new regions for new pages.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following code to retrieve all nodes of a type:

```
$type = 'example';
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('type', $type)
  ->condition('status', 1);
$nids = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
$nodes = node_load_multiple($nids);
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the following code to get all pages:

```
<?php
$type = "page"; // machine name for Basic Page
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type)); 
foreach($nodes as $node):
    // code here
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Just want to mention that node_load is the performance worst nightmare..

Comment: What would you recommend instead then?

Comment: I still didn't understand why not using views? Any way if you have a large number of nodes consider to use ajax to load the nodes - all depends on the amount of loaded content. If your method works fine (perfomance prespective) then use node_load. Think about possible changes in the future as well (adding video and view fields in that content type means a lot more server side calculations, adding mass amount of nodes to homepage, etc..)

Comment: The problem with views is that some parts of my content have views of their own. And since you can't load a view in a view (for as far as I know), I get stuck there. All pages get loaded, and some pages have sub-pages, which need to be visible in the content. I see no possibility in doing that with views.

Comment: I used a view to display a content type with a view field in one of our projects, have you tried it or you just assumed it can't work?

Comment: I don't just assume anything, but I'm relatively new to Drupal, so I need a bit more explanation when someone gives a suggestion of what to use. So when someone says: "Why don't you use that." I don't always straight away get what "that" is.